# Import React component with webpack 2

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

I'm trying to import a React component ([datetime](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime#usage)) to render but keep getting an error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

At one stage while developing it had worked, but I did not commit at that stage and thus can't recall what I did then (although I thought it was the import line I currently have). Now, as you can see I've tried every possible permutation for statements that I know of without success.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// require('react-datetime');
// var Datetime = require('react-datetime');
// import * as Datetime from 'react-datetime'
// import Datetime from 'react-datetime'
import {Datetime} from 'react-datetime'

function datepicker(d, cb) {
    return requestAnimationFrame( () => {
        console.log("datapicker")
        return ReactDOM.render(
            <Datetime />,
            document.getElementById('reactDate')
        );
    });
}

export default datepicker;
```

My webpack.config.js has this

```
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    // env: automatically determines the Babel plugins you need based on your supported environments
                    presets: ["env", 'react']
                }
            }
        }, {
```

If the code structure looks a little unusual it is because I am trying to embed it all in Elm.

If it helps, the export line of react-datetime reads:

```
module.exports = Datetime;
```

Comment: Don't you need at least to return the requestAnimationFrame function so you can call it?

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a try (see updated question) but it did not change the end result

Comment: What do see if you log out `Datetime`, your import? Is it by any chance a object with a `default` key?

Comment: With `import * as Datetime from 'react-datetime'` I do get `datepicker Object {default: Object}` although expanding further default seems to be pretty empty (bar the basics of `__proto__`. Otherwise I get `{}`

Comment: import {Datetime} from 'react-datetime'

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too with the only difference being that the error said `undefined` rather than `object`

Comment: Did you get an answer to this yet? I have the same problem